# What exercises are best for arm wrestling?

Tags: exercise

I would like to know exercises that are helpful for arm wrestling content only?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about one particular sport, and is more suited for http://sports.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should i ask this question to other domain?

Comment: If my suggestion passes, it will be moved automatically.

Comment: Many people harp on about strength being important, technique is AS important, if not more. You want to turn your wrist towards your body and pull down towards yourself, not just push sideways.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know that there are any “best” exercises for arm wrestling.  But, I would assume that any exercise that targets the muscles involved in arm wrestling would be of benefit.  To that end, I would tend to train forearms (hammer curls), biceps (curls), triceps (extensions), and, probably shoulders (presses).  A strong forearm should help with your grip.  Strong biceps and triceps will help stabilize your arm against your opponent.  And, lastly, strong shoulders may provide that last little push when your opponent is susceptible to being pinned.  If you’ve got a set of dumbbells available, they should allow you to train each of the body parts I’ve listed.

Answer (score 0):

Arm wrestling is more about technique than strength. Check this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkkL-bAH8H4

The world's strongest man competition winner loses to professional arm-wrestler. he has the strength and he's twice the size of the winner, but he lacks skills. Of course strength is required, but without technique, it's of no use.

Comment: Devon was able to hold Thor from a losing position (1:00). That was pure strength. Arm wrestling strength is different than strongman strength.